# How would I create this background effect?

Tags: c++, shader, demo-effects

What would you call the effect applied to the backgrounds in the Giygas fight of Earthbound, and the battle backgrounds in Mother 3? This is what I'm talking about.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tcaErqaoWek

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ubVnmeTRqhg

Now anyone know how I could go about this without using animated images, or using openGL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are also called [demo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demo_%28computer_programming%29) [effects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demo_effect). They are used on [demoscene](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demoscene) events, beside games.

Check out this [effect collection](http://demo-effects.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 1):

it's just a textured quad, with `sin` and `cos` applied to the texture coordinates

Comment: today, yeah it's the most straight forward way of doing it, use opengl or d3d -- the modern way is to do it in a shader

Comment: What kind of shader would that be called?

Comment: @William You can do this using a pixel shader.Here's a link with some examples http://www.facewound.com/tutorials/shader1/